Слова с двунаправленными связями (дуплексивы) в составном именном сказуемом, и не только
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Часто ли встречаются слова с двунаправленными связями? Достаточно часто, например в составном именном сказуемом, где именная часть выражена прилагательным (причастием, местоименным словом):  День был теплый.
Но замечаем мы это в том случае, если прилагательное стоит в форме Т.п., который задает глагол: День был (каким?) теплым.
Но иногда дуплексивы используются в других конструкциях, и это часто становится неожиданным для пользователей, как в этом вопросе.  Обсуждение было непростым, да и тема сложная. Слуги двух господ — так назвал дуплексивы один из участников.
P. S. Кстати, там задан еще один интересный вопрос:
(Остаться) одному – грамматический разбор
Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать "школьный" 
грамматический разбор предложений типа: "Я остался 
один" и "Мне тяжело одному". 

Увы, вопрос остался без ответа. Ваши предложения?

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
1. СОСТАВНОЕ ИМЕННОЕ СКАЗУЕМОЕ (как трёхчастная  конструкция)

Скоро наступит зима. В прошлом году зима была холодная/холодной.  Зимы вообще стали холодные/холодными.

Координация – это вид связи между подлежащим и сказуемым, которая выражается в согласовании подлежащего и сказуемого в своих общих категориях (род, лицо, число). Существительное (подлежащее)  задает число,  род или лицо глаголу (сказуемому), а глагол определяет именительный падеж существительного в двусоставном предложении.
Если сказуемое составное именное и именная часть выражена прилагательным, то влияние со стороны глагола  для прилагательного факультативное (И. п.  или Т.п.), что связано со стилистикой предложения.
В этом случае образуется трёхчастная конструкция, где прилагательное является дуплексивом,  то есть имеет двунаправленную связь: род и число прилагательного определяет существительное, а падеж  задает глагол.
Однако в случае И.п. для прилагательного влияние глагола НЕ ПРОЯВЛЕНО, поэтому мы считаем, что прилагательное согласовано с существительным в роде, числе и падеже.
Такая грамматика всем хорошо знакома, так что нет необходимости использовать понятие дуплексив. Но не все синтаксические конструкции так просты. В учебнике по грамматике Кустовой (в новых изданиях с 2013 года) дуплексивам посвящена отдельная тема.
2. КРАТКИЙ КОНСПЕКТ ТЕМЫ
Слова с двунаправленными связями (дуплексивы) относятся одновременно к существительному (или местоимению) и к глаголу: Он вернулся расстроенным. Она вернулась расстроенной.
Существительное (местоимение), к которому относится  дуплексив, может выполнять следующие функции:
(1) Подлежащее: Он один знал об этом. Она одна знала об этом.
(2) Детерминант с субъектным значением (в безличном предложении): Пете страшно одному (Д.п.). Маше страшно одной  (= в одиночестве).
ОДИН,  в зн. прил. 1. Без других, в отдельности от 
других, в одиночестве. Я живу одна. С кем ты 
пришёл? - Один. Не оставляйте детей одних! (без 
присмотра). Мы с тобой в доме совсем одни (никого 
больше  нет).

(3) Дополнение: Пусть помнит меня молодой/молодым.
Дуплексивами могут быть:
(1) Прилагательные:
Помнишь, тебя шестилетнего/шестилетнюю привели на поле. Однажды я застала его/ее  плачущим/плачущей.
(2) Местоименные слова (сам, весь, один, каждый):
Ему самому надо разобраться.  Ей самой надо разобраться
Мы открыли тайну ей одной/ему одному.
(3) Предложные группы (несогласованные определения): Он заснул в костюме. Он смешон со своими претензиями.
В конструкциях с дуплексивами возможны ВАРИАНТЫ ПАДЕЖЕЙ: Он спит одетый/одетым. Мы застали ее спящую/спящей. Ему выступать первым/ первому.
3. РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ
Дуплексивы (в трехчастных конструкциях)

Мне нужно остаться/побыть  одному (= в одиночестве). Безличное предложение, подлежащего нет, мне — субъектный детерминант в Д.п.

Остаться/ побыть (каком состоянии?) в одиночестве . Глагол задает Д.п. местоимению мне, а как он влияет на местоименное прилагательное одному?
Сравнить: Я хотел бы остаться один (в одиночестве). Мне нужно остаться одному (в одиночестве). Влияние глагола не проявлено в грамматике, и тогда происходит  согласование одному с местоимением мне в роде, числе и падеже.

Рассмотрим прилагательное одинокий в такой же позиции: Ему страшно остаться одиноким. Здесь прилагательное ведет себя как дуплексив, то есть согласуется с местоимением ему в роде и числе, но Т. п.  ему задает глагол. Управление остаться одинокому некорректно.

Он был хороший/хорошим (варианты падежей). В этом примере управление Т.п. со стороны глагола.
 ОСТАВИТЬ,  6. кого-что. Не изменить чьего-л. 
 состояния, положения и т.п.; сохранить в каком-л. 
 состоянии, положении и т.п. О. утюг включённым. О. 
 письмо незаконченным. О. вопрос открытым (не 
  решить). 


Sharon, что такое СЕ?

Это STACK EXCHANGE.
